# Integral $=\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha -1}Li_n (-\sigma x) Li_m(-\omega x^r)dx$.

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration

I am trying to calculate an integral that can be expressed in terms of infinite hypergeometric series by using transforms and Residue method, the integral is 
$$
I_{n,m}(\alpha,\sigma,\omega,r)=\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha -1}Li_n (-\sigma x) Li_m(-\omega x^r)dx
$$
where n,m are positive integers.  The complex parameters are $\alpha,\sigma,\omega$ and real $r\neq 0$ are defined so that the integral exists.  This is an integral containing polyLogs so we define the Polylogarithm function for $|z|\leq 1$ and $n\geq 2$ by a power series expression of the form
$$
Li_n(z)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j^n}, \ (|z| \leq 1).
$$
For $|z| > 1$ we obtain
$$
Li_n(z)=(-1)^{n+1}Li_n(z^{-1})-\frac{1}{n!}\ln^n(-z)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{j!}(1+(-1)^{n-j})(1-2^{1-n+j})\zeta(n-j)\ln^j(-z)
$$
where the Riemann Zeta function is given by $\zeta(n-j)$ and the logarithm is defined on the principle sheet. I was thinking of also using an integral representation of the polyLogs which are given by
$$
Li_n(-z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma -i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(-s)}{(-s)^{n-1}} z^{-s} ds, \ (-1<\gamma <0, |\arg z| < \pi, \ n=0,1,2,...)
$$
and inserting into this $I_{n,m}$...Any ideas on what do, I need a complete solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Bounty Again Soon?

Comment: @draks... Yes I am putting it up as a bounty (again) since nobody could help last time I put it up for +500.